# Как в битрикс массово изменить значения в доп. поле?

Tags: битрикс

Есть у меня рубрика, и в рубрике, в дополнительном поле есть телефон. 
Этих рубрик больше 4000

Вопрос. 
Как массово изменить телефон на другой?

Comment: Телефон у всех один или у каждой рубрики свой? Самый простой вариант написать скрипт или агента который отработает и сделает это для вас. Потом его отключить.

Comment: Телефон одинаковый у всех.

Comment: По поводу крипта - я только за, но вопрос в том что я не совсем понимаю где вообще искать значения этих полей))

Comment: Найдите в настройках инфоблока код коля, а дальше скармливайте его  апишным функциям.